# Closure of interior of a set is equal to the closure of the set if and only if the interior of the set is not empty.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'll denote the interior of set A as $int(A)$ and it's closure as $\overline{A}$.

I want to show that $\overline{int(A)} = \overline{A} \iff int(A) \ne \emptyset$

For the first part, I tried to write:

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $\overline{int(A)} = \overline{A}$ then for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $\lim a_{n} = a$ and also there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(a - \epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subset A$.

I don't know what to do from here. I can see that if $int(A) = \emptyset$ the sequence and the neighbourhood won't exist, but how do I get there?

And for the second part I wrote:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $int(A) = \emptyset$, then for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $\nexists$ $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subset A$, so there is no sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $\lim (a_{n}) = a$ then  $\overline{int(A)} = \emptyset$.

Here I don't know how to conclude as well, was trying to find a contradiction by showing that $\overline{A} \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: The title of your question isn't the same as the claim you are trying to prove

Comment: You should fix the typo in the statement. But one direction is false.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, just fixed them.

Comment: As I said, one direction is false. However, if you assume $A\ne\emptyset$, then you can see (by contrapositive?) that $\implies$ is easy.

Comment: If $A=\overline {int(A)}$ then $A$ is called a regular closed set. If $B=int(\overline B)$ then $B$ is called a regular open set. Another example of a non-regular closed set with non-empty interior is $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$ in the space $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Suppose $A=\varnothing$ then $\Rightarrow$ is false.

Answer (score 3):

$A=\mathbb Q$ is an example where the interior is empty but $\overline{int(A)} \neq \overline{A}$. $A=\mathbb Q \cup (0,1)$ is an example where the interior is not empty and $\overline{int(A)} \neq \overline{A}$. So there is no  valid result of this type.

Comment: We also have $A=\bar A=int(A)=\overline {int(A)}$ when $A=\emptyset.$